# Clip a GeoJSON layer based on polygon drawing

Tags: openlayers, geojson, vector, clip

I want to know if is possible clip a GeoJSON layer based on a feature drawn with drawing tools in OpenLayers. I followed this steps (https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/layer-clipping-vector.html) and I could make it work for WMS layer, but is not working for GeoJSON, I attach an image where you can see what im trying to achieve, blue squares is GeoJSON layer, I could clip OSM but not the blue squares.

This is the code i´m using to clip layers:

```
layer.on('postrender', (e) => {

                const style = new ol.style.Style({
                    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                        color: 'black',
                    }),
                });

                const vectorContext = ol.render.getVectorContext(e);
                e.context.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-in';
                this.source.forEachFeature(function(feature) {
                    vectorContext.drawFeature(feature, style);
                });
                e.context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';

            });

osm.on('postrender', (e) => {

            const style = new ol.style.Style({
                fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                    color: 'black',
                }),
            });

            const vectorContext = ol.render.getVectorContext(e);
            e.context.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-in';
            this.source.forEachFeature(function(feature) {
                vectorContext.drawFeature(feature, style);
            });
            e.context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';

        });
```

layer refers to geojson (blue squares) layer, and osm to the raster layer from OSM

[image: figure]

Comment: Works without problems from me, see JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/TomazicM/738psazj/.